# HTML & CSS: How do I completely remove the scroll-bars on the side of <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem removing the scroll bars on the side of my  tags. I have read something about adding the overflow: hidden attribute, but I am still in doubt of how to (and where to) apply the attribute. Can you help me out?

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Circle Motion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="outer-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="top">  
            </div>

            <div id="box_1">
            <img src="chrome_400x400.png" />
            </div>

            <div id="box_2">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#outer-wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: EAFFDB;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: EAFFDB;
overflow: auto;
}

#top {
width: 900px;
height: 110px;
margin-top: 35px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 35px;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

#box_1 {
width: 430px;
height: 430px;
background-color: black;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
float:left;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

#box_1 img {
margin: 15px 0px;
}

#box_2 {
width: 430px;
height: 430px;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
float:right;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
}       

#box_1 img {
margin: 15px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in your `#wrapper` styling;

```
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: #EAFFDB; /*note you were missing this hashtag before the color, which might work, but this is safer*/
overflow: hidden; /*this was auto, while it should be hidden*/
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Why does this div have a scrollbar to begin with, it's not normal?!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should apply `overflow:hidden` to the element you have to remove the scroll bars from.

And you are missing the hashtags(#) before the hex color codes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden;` instead of `overflow: auto;` in `#wrapper` class