# Remove scroll bar from div

Tags: html, css

Created a navigation bar and looks good in firefox then behold, in chrome and ie theres a scroll bar. How can I set the navigation so theres no scroll bar?

```css
  header {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: -7px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.nav {
  width: 600px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  .nav img a {
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
      <div>
        <a href="index.html"><img width="103px" border="0" height="24" src="nav-01_over.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="company.html"><img src="nav-02.gif" width="103px" border="0" height="24"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="products.html"><img src="nav-03.gif" width="103px" border="0" height="24"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="solutions.html"><img src="nav-04.gif" width="103px" border="0" height="24"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="investors.html"><img src="nav-05.gif" width="103px" border="0" height="24"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe add `overflow: hidden;` to the thing that is scrolling?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238036/html-css-how-do-i-completely-remove-the-scroll-bars-on-the-side-of-div?rq=1

Answer (score 17):

In your css, use `overflow:hidden`:

```
.nav div {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Also, your `.nav div` is missing a close brace

Answer (score 7):

By changing the CSS and adding:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the CSS `overflow-y:hidden` to anything scrolling. It will hide the vertical scrollbar. If it's horizontal, use `overflow-x: hidden`.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();//drag out of window
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "window"});
 });
```

Comment: That's not CSS, and it's not even clear that the OP has jQuery or similar installed in the project.